# Vertical navigation bar width

Tags: html, css

I have included my CSS and HTML for the vertical navigation bar. My problem is that I want each link button to have the same width which I am failing to do. I tried using width but it didn't work? I would also like to be able to get rid of the white lines in between the links.

```
<style>
        .ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 0;
            background-color: grey;
        }
        .list{
            display: inline;
            width: 200px;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .link:link{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: grey;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .link:visited{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .link:hover{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .link:active{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: yellow;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <ul class="ul">
            <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">HTML</a></li>
            <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">Cascading Style Sheet</a></li>
            <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">Javascript</a></li>
            <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">PHP</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: `width` for all the list elements is same but you gave background color to `.link` class. apply background color to `list` class and check once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplified it a bit more by getting rid of the class on your links and some of the redundant css. The white line was extra padding you had. And the color needed to be on the list.

```css
.ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.list {
  display: inline;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.list:visited{
  background-color: blue;
}
.list:hover{
  background-color: black;
}
.list:active{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
       <li class="list"><a href="http://www.google.ca">HTML</a></li>
       <li class="list"><a href="http://www.google.ca">Cascading Style Sheet</a></li>
       <li class="list"><a href="http://www.google.ca">Javascript</a></li>
       <li class="list"><a href="http://www.google.ca">PHP</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can also simplify this more by getting rid of the class on your <li> and naming the <ul> class something more descriptive like 'menu'. Then you can nest your css like ".menu li{ }" and ".menu a{ }".

Comment: works perfectly as wanted. Thanks for the tip as well

Comment: No problem @mouse_s

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the **.link** class a width and give height to your **.list** class.  Like so:

```
.ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 0;
            background-color: grey;
        }
        .list{
            width: 200px;
            display: block;
            height: 19px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .link:link{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: grey;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .link:visited{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .link:hover{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .link:active{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: yellow;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .link {
            width: 150px;
            display:block;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/GunWanderer/zmL9boso/1/

Comment: if i eliminate padding from .list the links overlap

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the display of your a elements to block. e.g. `.list{ .link: display: block; }`

```css
        .ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 30%;
        }

        .list{
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: gray;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .link{
            display: block;
        }
        .link:link{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: grey;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .link:visited{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .link:hover{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .link:active{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: yellow;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
 <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">HTML</a></li>
 <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">Cascading Style Sheet</a></li>
<li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">Javascript</a></li>
<li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">PHP</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ul element had a width of 0. All I had to do was set it to something. I picked 200px because you set list to be 200.

```
<style>
        li a {
          display: block;
        }
        .ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 200px;
            background-color: grey;
        }
        .list{
            display: inline;
            width: 200px;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .link:link{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: grey;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .link:visited{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .link:hover{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .link:active{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: yellow;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <ul class="ul">
            <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">HTML</a></li>
            <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">Cascading Style Sheet</a></li>
            <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">Javascript</a></li>
            <li class="list"><a class="link" href="http://www.google.ca">PHP</a></li>
        </ul>
```

I can't see a white line between links...

http://codepen.io/zsawaf/pen/VjXKXV

Comment: This is a good start, but once you get more advanced, look into flexbox. It allows you to minimize setting static widths and heights, and everything aligns perfectly.

Comment: I'm using google chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m and once i changed width:200px in .ul the only thing that changed is that now it all looks aligned but once you hover over the links they are still the same size

Comment: OH, you want the hovers to be the same width. I didn't understand your question. Give me a second.

Comment: Check the codepen again, I updated it. Basically, if you want an "a" tag to wrap around its parent, you need to always set it display: block.

Comment: It worked, they are all the same same length but the layout is completely changed is there a way to keep the original one? My end goal is to have 4 vertical link buttons same length one on top of the other with no padding around them and between

Answer (score 0):

add `background-color: grey;` to your `.list` class and check the result.

replay back if you didn't get your result

Comment: it looks aligned, but the links still kept the same size as before if you hover over them or click on them